# JS from codepan doesn't work anywhere except codepan

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code works when I open it in codepan in IE 10 or 11, but it doesn't work when I try to do the same in jsfiddle or anywhere in IE 10 or 11. I have already tried copy/paste and export as archive, so what's wrong?

[codepan](https://codepen.io/jonneal/pen/EKPONK)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlekseiSevrukov/9ua5h7qc/)

```js
if ('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-object-fit]'), function (image) {
   (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).background = 'url("' + image.src + '") no-repeat 50%/' + (image.currentStyle ? image.currentStyle['object-fit'] : image.getAttribute('data-object-fit'));

   image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' width=\'' + image.width + '\' height=\'' + image.height + '\'%3E%3C/svg%3E';
  });
 });
}
```

```css
img {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
}

img[data-object-fit="contain"] {
 object-fit: contain;
}

img[data-object-fit="cover"] {
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/1080x200" data-object-fit="cover">

<img src="https://placehold.it/1080x200" data-object-fit="contain">
```

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? Doesn't run, throws an error, doesn't pass the conditional check at the beginning?

Comment: Also note that `object-fit` is not actually supported in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @JaredSmith It doesn't throw any mistake and the conditional check at the beginning is working well, but result is like there is no any js

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes I know, that's why I need this polyfill for IE and Edge

Comment: So are there errors in IE's console? Did you add breakpoints and see if things are called?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I checked the first condition and the array of elements I need, it's all works well, you can see it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AlekseiSevrukov/9ua5h7qc/

Comment: If you knew it wouldn't work, why didn't you just google for a polyfill? https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/ Voting to close this as off-topic.

Comment: @JaredSmith please, read again the topic. I have found the polyfill for object-fit here https://codepen.io/jonneal/pen/EKPONK and it works great but when I try to use it in my project it doesn't work, so I try to understand why it works only in codepan

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Just for reference though, that polyfill I linked is 230 lines. You-re ad-hoc solution might not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anton Chukanov, your idea was right, bit I have found that on jsfiddle I can choose the type of load js, so default type is "onLoad" and when I choose "no wrap - in body" or "no wrap - in head" it started work properly. So I think it easier to change load type than the code.
Thanks everybody who was envolved in this question!

Answer (score 0):

Codepan just fires 'DOMContentLoaded' event on run your code, but jsFiddle doesn't. Check `document.readyState`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rpjedb

https://jsfiddle.net/9ua5h7qc/1/